# Event extraction vs N-ary relation extraction

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp, information-extraction

What is the difference between an event and an n-ary relation?

I am trying to differentiate between the two and eventually focus on the task of extraction. For example, from the given sentence:

```
Peter completed B.Sc. in physics from Boston University.
```

Extracted n-ary relation:

```
r(Peter, B.Sc., physics, Boston University)
```

*(Assuming that the entities are already labeled)*

For the problem of event extraction, we have datasets like `ACE 2005` event extraction corpus. However, I haven't come across any corpus for n-ary relation extraction. Is anyone aware of any such corpus which might facilitate n-ary relation extraction?

Answer (score 1):

Once you get your entitites from your text using libraries like opennlp and stanfordnlp, you need to add those to your vocab like something that has been done [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/#vocabulary). Their plan was to produce a suggested vocabulary for describing that a class represents an n-ary relation and for defining mappings between n-ary relations in RDF and OWL and other languages.

They've considered many attributes to describe a relation.

they've used blank nodes in RDF to represent instances of a relation.

```
:Christine
      a       :Person ;
      :has_diagnosis _:Diagnosis_Relation_1 .

:_Diagnosis_relation_1
      a       :Diagnosis_Relation ;
      :diagnosis_probability :HIGH;
      :diagnosis_value :Breast_Tumor_Christine .
```

similarly you can do

```
:Peter
      a       :Person ;
      :has_degree _:Degree_1 .

:_Degree_1
      a       :Degree ;
      :degree_name :B.Sc;
      :degree_value :Physics;
      :degree_place :Boston_University .
```

Follow [this](http://nlp.stanford.edu/courses/cs224n/2015/reports/17.pdf) for some insight.

Hope this helps!